# Django - CSV Reader not working if csv file contains a blank line

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a function in a view that I am using to upload CSV data and write to a DB. The function works properly if the CSV file does not have any blank lines. However, if the CSV file has any blank lines, the function does not read any data at all. Below is the extract of the code:

```
data_set = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
created = None
created_records = 0
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created = GrowerMaster.objects.update_or_create(
        grower_no           =column[0],
        surname             =column[1],
        name                =column[2],
        initials            =column[3],
        area                =column[11],
        national_id         =column[15],
        contractor          =column[21]
    )

    if created:
        created_records+=1


if created is None:
    messages.warning(request, "No records were read from file. Please check the file and try again")

if created_records > 0:
    messages.success(request, f"{created_records} new records have been imported successfully")

else:
    messages.warning(request, "No new records were imported.")
```

Where and how can I fix this problem such that a csv file with a blank line can still be processed successfully.

The screenshot below shows the line that is causing the problem. If I delete that line manually, the file uploads successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check that it has number of columns required before parsing the row. Otherwise you're going to be trying to access columns that don't exist and end up crashing.

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    if len(column) >= HEADER_LENGTH:
        _, created = GrowerMaster.objects.update_or_create(
            grower_no           =column[0],
            surname             =column[1],
            name                =column[2],
            initials            =column[3],
            area                =column[11],
            national_id         =column[15],
            contractor          =column[21]
        )
```

Alternatively try to handle the exception (which is probably going to be `IndexError`):

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    try:
        _, created = GrowerMaster.objects.update_or_create(
            grower_no           =column[0],
            surname             =column[1],
            name                =column[2],
            initials            =column[3],
            area                =column[11],
            national_id         =column[15],
            contractor          =column[21]
        )
        if created:
            created_records+=1
    except IndexError:
        # skip the row
        pass
```

Comment: Hi @Christian W. Thanks for your contribution. I tried both methods but still no luck. The blank line appears to be the last line in the csv file - usually. What else can I try?

Comment: With the information you have provided, I'm not sure anything else can be said without error logs. The only certain thing that can be said is that your original code _will_ fail to read csv files as it encounters rows that have smaller number of elements than 21.

Comment: W I have tried to update the question by showing you the file that is causing the problem. I don't have any errors being thrown so I cannot show any errors. I hope this gives you more information to get the picture. Thank you.